# pthread_mutex value getting changed after unlock

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I am running SnS on android(L) BT app and using GKI calls under bluedroid. All GKI calls are called from various threads of BT app and we are protecting it by mutex(bionic). It works fine if BT turns on\off for 700+ iteration but after that suddenly i see that the moment mutex gets unlocked by one thread, its value becomes 2 and it does not get back to its old value. I am intitializing the mutex in default manner and really not sure what is happening. In fact i had put buffer padding around mutex to avoid from any corruption but buffer with pattern is not overwritten at all but only the mutex value changes to `2`. all threads waiting for this mutex starves.

Please suggest why it can change its value to `2` and how I can stop it.

```
  Line 3121: 01-01 03:30:30.200  1117 15470 E GKI_LINUX: LOCK TRYING : gki addr 0xa4e18e40 **value 16384** value before=1515870810 and after=1515870810
                Line 3123: 01-01 03:30:30.200  1117 15470 E GKI_LINUX: LOCKED : gki addr 0xa4e18e40 value 1013858305 value before=1515870810 and after=1515870810

  Line 3139: 01-01 03:30:30.200  1117 15470 E GKI_LINUX: UNLOCKED : gki addr 0xa4e18e40 **value 2** value before=1515870810 and after=1515870810  **//ideally it should have been 16384**
```

P.S. : newbie to linux

Code :

```
//This function initializes the mutex.
void GKI_init(void)
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    tGKI_OS             *p_os;

    memset (&gki_cb, 0, sizeof (gki_cb));

    gki_buffer_init();
    gki_timers_init();
    alarm_service_init();

    gki_cb.com.OSTicks = (UINT32) times(0);

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);

#ifndef __CYGWIN__
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP);
#endif
    p_os = &gki_cb.os;
    pthread_mutex_init(&p_os->GKI_mutex, &attr);
    /* pthread_mutex_init(&GKI_sched_mutex, NULL); */
    /*Store mutex value in backup */
    p_os->origval = p_os->GKI_mutex.value;
    ALOGE(" backup mutex value is = %d ",p_os->origval);

#if (GKI_DEBUG == TRUE)
    pthread_mutex_init(&p_os->GKI_trace_mutex, NULL);
#endif 

    struct sigevent sigevent;
    memset(&sigevent, 0, sizeof(sigevent));
    sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    sigevent.sigev_notify_function = (void (*)(union sigval))bt_alarm_cb;
    sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = NULL;
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sigevent, &posix_timer) == -1) {
        ALOGE("%s unable to create POSIX timer: %s", __func__, strerror(errno));
        timer_created = false;
    } else {
        timer_created = true;
    }
}


void GKI_disable (void)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&gki_cb.os.GKI_mutex);
}

void GKI_enable (void)
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gki_cb.os.GKI_mutex);
//Just after this mutex value is getting changed i.e. GKI_mutex.value =2
}
```

Everytime GKI_disable/ GKI_enable is called before accessing common resources.

Comment: @ Gábor Bakos, shared the code as well.

Comment: Any body got any pointers??..i am having no clue why this is happening.

Comment: The code shown looks ok. So the issue to what you observe might lie elsewhere. It is propably a memory corruption that happend way before the momemt of failure. You might like to consider running your program using a memory check like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org).

Comment: You also might like to add the C or C++ tag to you question to widen the possible audience.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys..I actually added the pad of 100 bytes with pattern before and after the mutex to see for any corruption but only the mutex value got changed. So possibly not a mem corruption case. There is something that is specifically changing the value.

Comment: You didn't show implementation of bt_alarm_cb, do you in some call-path lock or unlock your mutex in sig.handler??

Comment: In your code, `p_os->GKI_mutex` is `pthread_mutex_t`-type? Do you mean "mutex value" is `p_os->GKI_mutex.value`? If so, you take a look inside "mutex object", and it's BAD idea.